# How to change Vuforia stereo camera screen size?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resize, vuforia

I am developing a game with stereo camera using vuforia. Is it possible for us to change the screen display size to a bigger one? Below is the example;

[What I have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5RF1V.png)

[What I expected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPZBE.jpg)

Comment: Did you try using a different cardboard viewer?

Comment: what do u mean? different HMD? i have test on 4 different smart phone but the display still small. there is big black space around it

Comment: Could you improve your question by providing the code that you use for the Stereo viewer? Maybe its a certain SDK (i.e. Cardboard or GVR)

Comment: I used Vuforia own settings. i did not use any cardboard or GVR settings. in Vuforia Configuration setting, i choose video-see through for Eyewear Type, Stereo Camera Config = Vuforia, and Viewer Type = Generic Carboard

Comment: Please refer to this [link](https://library.vuforia.com/articles/Solution/Integrating-Cardboard-to-the-ARVR-Sample) and try method one and two.